# ContextMenu StaysOpen is not working

Tags: wpf

I am showing a `UserControl` inside `ContextMenu`. Futhermore in that `UserControl` I am showing a `Popup` which contains some buttons and datagrid. All the data in `Popup` loads during runtime.

The problem is `ContextMenu` ignores the property `StaysOpen` even though it is set to `true`.

The `Popup` does stay open when I set `StaysOpen` to `true` in code behind but `ContextMenu` doesn't.

I tried it with following code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid>
   <Popup Name="popupState" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch}" PopupAnimation="Slide" Placement="Bottom" Focusable="True" AllowsTransparency="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">

   <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Background="GhostWhite" Name="btnSelectAll" Click="btnSelectAll_Click" Width="30" Height="30">

   <my:DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" RowHeaderWidth="0" Margin="5,5,5,1" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="DGTeamCommunicator" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#D6D7D6" GridLinesVisibility="None">
      <my:DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="Auto" MinWidth="30">
         <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="True" ContextMenuService.HasDropShadow="True">
                  <Button Name="btnCall"  Click="btnCall_Click" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="True">
                  </Button>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
        </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </my:DataGrid>
</Popup>
```

My requirement is to Prevent the `Popup` as well as `ContextMenu` from closing when the buttons in `Popup` is clicked.

Kindly provide me a solution for this.

Comment: Post more code please

Comment: Thanks for your time dev-hedgehog, and i updated the snippet. have a look and give me a solution

Comment: Take a look at my answer :) I edited your question to make things clear and understandable. I hope you do not mind. Btw, here is +1 from me for the question. It is a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that this behavior is by design. ContextMenu is defined to display few menus and when one of them is being clicked the ContextMenu internally sets the IsOpen to false.

The good news is that behavior should stay so and for any other customization you should take a Popup instead of ContextMenu. BUT if you MUST use ContextMenu for whatever reason here is a workaround:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>
        Popup Demo
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <local:StaysOpenContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu1" StaysOpen="True">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="100" TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup1" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tbx}" StaysOpen="True">
                        <Button Content="click me"/>
                    </Popup>
                </StackPanel>
            </local:StaysOpenContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
    <Button Click="OnClick">Close Popup</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

You will need a custom ContextMenu to get the job done:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Popup1.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Popup1.IsOpen = false;
        this.ContextMenu1.CloseContextMenu();
    }
}

public class StaysOpenContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    private bool mustStayOpen;

    static StaysOpenContextMenu()
    {
        IsOpenProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(StaysOpenContextMenu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, null, CoerceIsOpen));
        StaysOpenProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(StaysOpenContextMenu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChanged, CoerceStaysOpen));
    }

    private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaysOpenContextMenu menu = (StaysOpenContextMenu)d;
        menu.mustStayOpen = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }

    private static object CoerceStaysOpen(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(IsOpenProperty);
        return basevalue;
    }

    private static object CoerceIsOpen(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        StaysOpenContextMenu menu = (StaysOpenContextMenu)d;
        if (menu.StaysOpen && menu.mustStayOpen)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return basevalue;
    }

    public void CloseContextMenu()
    {
        this.mustStayOpen = false;
        this.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```