# Contextmenu StaysOpen property is not working at all

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very odd problem with contextmenu. Consider this simple code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="CMenu" StaysOpen="True" >
            <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Item 2">
                <MenuItem Header="Sub item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Sub item 2" />
                <MenuItem Header="Sub item 3" />
                <MenuItem Header="Sub item 4" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Item 3" />
            <MenuItem Header="Item 4" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    <Label Content="ContextMenu Test" />
    <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

I set staysopen to true, however, as soon as I click wherever outside of the contextmenu it closes. What is this property used for ? How can I prevent contextmenu from closing ? (Clicking clickme button traces StaysOpen status, it's always true)

Comment: Hmm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20370672/424129

Comment: @EdPlunkett My case is different. I don't want contextmenu to stay open when I click menu items. It's ok to close. I just don't want the menu to close when I click outside its content.

Comment: It is the same meaning: you need to avoid closing and keep it opened.
Use Popup and control when you need to open and close it manually.

Comment: Rather a ContextMenu, I'd create a secondary window (which is basically the same), ensuring the "Owner" property set to the main (or whatever else) window. Your case is a typical "modeless" (if the outside interaction is allowed), or "modal" (when the foreground window must be closed).

Answer (score 2):

To keep Menu Open even after click, you have to set below property to true for each menuitem

```
StaysOpenOnClick="True"
```

so for your requirement, your code would be like below:

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="CMenu" StaysOpen="True" >
                                       <MenuItem Header="Item 1" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" StaysOpenOnClick="True">
                        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 1" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 2" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 3" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 4" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 3" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 4" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>

            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <Label Content="ContextMenu Test" />
        <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Setting StaysOpenOnClick to true on a menuitem prevents context menu from closing when that menuitem is clicked and still closes when you click outside of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to use Popup instead:

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Popup IsOpen="True"
               StaysOpen="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Panel}}}">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBoxItem Content="1" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="2" />
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
        <Label Content="ContextMenu Test" />
        <Button Content="ClickMe" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Nevertheless, you should take care for location of this popup according to movement of your window. Means redefine its X and Y.

Comment: I have already considered using a popup instead but I want it to look like a real contextmenu, and since I use custom styles for contextmenu, I don't want to mess around.

Comment: There is no choice here. You have to implement your own "context menu" from Popup because original Context Menu has been built to be closed.

Comment: So what is the purpose of StaysOpen property on context menu ? Am I missing something ?